# Assign contributor role to application using az cli

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I am trying to assign contributor to app using following command:

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac -n "Terraform Cloud" --role Contributor --scopes /subscriptions/<id> --sdk-auth
```

I get following issue:

> Changing "Terraform-Cloud" to a valid URI of
> "http://Terraform-Cloud", which is the required format used for
> service principal names Values of identifierUris property must use a
> verified domain of the organization or its subdomain:
> 'http://Terraform-Cloud'

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding to this [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/19892)

> **Context** 
> According to the announcement of
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-breaking-changes#appid-uri-in-single-tenant-applications-will-require-use-of-default-scheme-or-verified-domains,
> AAD service will block creating single tenant applications with
> invalid idefntifierUris after 2021-10-15.
>
> **Impact** 
> Azure CLI command az ad sp create-for-rbac before 2.25.0 which
> sets invalid idefntifierUris will fails with 400 badrequest, such as
>
> Values of identifierUris property must use a verified domain of the
> organization or its subdomain: 'http://azure-cli-2021-10-20-03-53-05'
>
> **Solution** 
> az ad sp create-for-rbac has been updated so that now it
> doesn't create identifierUris at all (#18312). Please update to Azure
> CLI 2.25.0 or newer. We recommend always using the latest version.

So what I did is upgrading my az cli to latest version using `az upgrade`

When upgrade was done, I ran the same command that is mentioned in the question and all works as expected.